# ASP.NET 4.6 - Castle Project MVC - Web site problem, sometimes when users request same resource the server swap users responses

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, castle, asp.net-4.6

Sometime when users access same web site resource they get swapped responses.

What should happen:

User A request: site.com/getOrderList => User A get: User A content data response

User B request: site.com/getOrderList => User B get: User B content data response

What happens sometimes:

User A request: site.com/getOrderList => User A get: **User B** content data response

OR

User B request: site.com/getOrderList => User B get: **User A** content data response

In this case, one user can see the order list from other user.

But, if I click homepage button everything becomes normal again.

Swapping responses happens for one request only, in the next request the user will receive the correct response.

I can replicate the problem locally in IIS Express with automated tests, but the problem is intermittent.

If you need more details just ask.

Comment: Are you accessing a static property, class or member while generating the response? Can you share some code please?

Comment: Pretty hard to understand what is happening without any code or debug. How do you know the user A is user A?

Comment: is this problem replicated on local developmeny machine or only happen on production server? if its not code issue, often times misconfigured load balancer can mess up responses. narrow down the problem and put [mcve] in the question for clarity.

Comment: @BagusTesa You give some ideas to try understand what is happening using minimal reproducible example, I will try reproduce the problem in a new project. About your question, yes, the problem is replicated on local development.

Comment: @BrunoCanto *"but the problem is intermittent."* - do you have some kind caching mechanism? especially self-made ones.